# Detecting failed struct field - govalidator

Tags: go

I'm experimenting with govalidator - https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator

I would like to know whether it's possible to detect which field in a struct has failed a validation check so that I can return an appropriate error message. So for example:

```
type Post struct {
    Title    string `valid:"alphanum,required"`
    Message  string `valid:"required"`
}

result, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(post)
if err != nil {
    //if title is missing then show error 1
    //if message is missing then show error 2
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be similar to [issue/67](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator/issues/67):

> At this moment it gives error like this:

```
Title: My123 does not validate as alpha;
AuthorIP: 123 does not validate as ipv4;
```

> I create function [`ErroByField(e error, field string)`](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator/blob/088ee1700509921c0970999fc56bc4641676b3a0/validator.go#L769-L786) that will return error for specified field of struct or empty string otherwise, I hope that it will be helpful.
>
> For example:

```
type Post struct {
    Title    string `valid:"alpha,required"`
    Message  string `valid:"ascii"`
    AuthorIP string `valid:"ipv4"`
}

post := &Post{"My123", "duck13126", "123"}
result, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(post)

titleError := govalidator.ErrorByField(err, "Title")
if titleError != "" {
    println(titleError) // -> My123 does not validate as alpha
}
```

Comment: Ah - I hadn't noticed that issue. So the `ErrorByField` function is already in the package?

Comment: @tommyd456 yes, commit https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator/commit/9cae1e03cfb752a931e0429bedcc3ebb3a0aad24, that is tag v2.